# Playwright tests failing 50% of time on screenshot compare in headless mode

Tags: screenshot, playwright, headless

Running a playwright test that compares a screenshot taken during the test execution to a known good screen shot 'golden'. When executing sometimes the screenshot taken has a scroll bar in the middle of the page, sometimes my image does not. My gold jpg doesn't have a scroll bar, so when I run the test and the screenshot gets a scroll bar, it fails. I don't understand why it's inconsistent running headless. Is there any way I can specify for headless execution on Chromium, the screen size it should use, the screen resolution?  Has anyone experienced this? Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set all those parameters in `playwright.config.js`

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#global-configuration

or advanced:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced

Also I suggest narrowing down the area of the screenshot to a specific element and not whole page, or you can set different screenshot comparison options:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#page-assertions-to-have-screenshot-2

Note the `clip` and `mask` option